# Crystal Report Layout issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I am designing a Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2012 and can't seem to manage the position of a vertical line. I need the line to stick the right edge of the page, but it resists. Even if I managed to align it on the right, it displays at a different position after deploying the software on another machine, even when just previewing.

Setting the page size to A4 doesn't help. How can I make this easier on me?

---

**Designer View:**

[image]

In Report preview the right hand side line is not shown properly:

[image]

If I move the line a bit to the left, like this...

[image]

...the row background goes beyond the line in preview.

[image]

Comment: background goes beyond the line because your layout is extending more to the right... decrease the size of the layout or draw the line at the end of the layout

Comment: you need to check if the vertical line end points touches exactly to the horizontal line end points.

Comment: @Siva it i do so. the line is not properly displayed.. you case it is cutting on the edge

Comment: @RahulHendawe it touches and extends vertically.. but i need this line object to the edges of the row

Comment: I guess it is moving to bew page...decrease the width of layout and check

Comment: @Siva yes, but in report designer, I have not put it outside. i have attached the first and second pic. you can see the line cutting from right-hand side.

Comment: You also might try setting the default printer to No Printer. I'm not sure if this feature exists in Visual Studio, but it's a lifesaver in the original Crystal Reports designer.

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck using a Box object for the outer layers and only using lines for the inside columns. Just like the lines, the Box can span multiple sections and will resize vertically if the report has extra lines added in. At the very least this will make sure the outside borders always connect perfectly.

If you're still having problems with precision, try setting the Size and Position. Set the Left and Top to zero, and calculate the appropriate Width value based on the Width of your report.

In the end Crystal reports are a little finicky when it comes to layout, and different viewers/printers might jostle stuff around a little. But unless the report has a dynamic width, you should be able to get it pretty close with a Box and very specific Size/Position values.